# What property exposes the message contents of the Okhttp response

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have a backend that I was trying to Post a user registration request with password "12345" using okhttp and it failed.

It took me several hours that I figured that actually backend rejects all-numeric passwords with response code of 400.

The way that I find out the issue was to send same post request in Python, and it was when I received detail of the issue in Python shell:

```
>>>request.content
b'{"password1":["This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.","This password is too common.","This password is entirely numeric."]}'
```

I was wondering how could I get similar message in android studio from the **response** of request, which is as follows:

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            m_textView.setText("Successfull!");
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                }
            }
```

in debug mode, this response has many properties but I don't see any of them pointing to the useful content that python brings up,

I appreciate any advise,

Thanks,

Comment: Don't you have it there, in `response.body()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like the following returns what I needed:

```
response.body().string()
```